Show that the points $M, N, P, Q$ are coplanar and concyclic.
the question
Consider the tetrahedron $ABCD$, with the perpendicular edge $AD$
on the $(BCD)$ plane. Let $X$ be some point of the edge $AD$ and the point $Y$ on
$(AD)$ such that $m(∠Y CD) = m(∠DAB)$. The circle with the center $O_1$,which is on $CD$ passing through
through $C$ and $X$ intersect $AC$ and $CY$ in $P$ and $Q$ is denoted by $C_1$, and the circle with
the center $O_2$,which is on $BD$ passing through $B$ and $X$ cuts $AB$ and $BY$ in $M$ and $N$, denoted by
$C_2$. Show that the points $M, N, P, Q$ are coplanar and concyclic.
my idea
drawings


I tried working with angles and inscribed quadrilaterals but got to  nothing useful.
I don't know how to start! I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

I think you forgot to define $X$ (or is not clear whether it is arbitrary or similar to $Y$).

@Zumzumike I realised that the angle congruencies are a mistake, so forget about them...

What is denoted by $m(\angle YCD)$? Just a degree measure of an angle?

Yes same question as @Aig . What's m?

@Aig yes, you are right

@Gwen  it is the degree measure of an angle

Why not just write $\angle YCD=\angle DAB$?

@TonyK this is how i was learnt at school, so i guess it just became something normal for me....of course you can write it without m

@TonyK My guess is, in some schools they say that these two angles are not equal. And formally, this is true. This is two different elements of the set of all angles. They are congruent, not equal. Also, their degree measure is the same. Ionela, please confirm if that’s the case.

@Aig yes, their degree measure is the same...this is what i know

The key is to realize that this three-dimensional problem is really just a folded two-dimensional problem. Unfold the figure along hinge $AD$ to get a nice, flat $\triangle ABC$.

Define $\beta := \angle BAD$ and $\gamma := \angle CAD$. As a minor convenience, we'll assume $\angle A$ is non-obtuse (the obtuse case is largely the same), and define $\alpha := 90^\circ-\beta-\gamma$.
The condition $\angle YCD=\angle DAB\;(=\beta)$ implies that $\overline{CY}\perp\overline{AB}$; this makes $Y$ the orthocenter of our flattened triangle, which in turn implies $\overline{BY}\perp\overline{AC}$ and $\angle YBD=\angle DAC\;(=\gamma)$. Moreover, $\angle ABY=\angle ACY=\alpha$.
Define $X'$ as the reflection of $X$ in $\overline{BC}$. The circle conditions imply that $BMNXX'$ and $CPQXX'$ are each cyclic. The fact that the circles have common chord $\overline{XX'}$ whose extension contains $A$ implies that $A$ has a common power with respect to both circles; likewise for $Y$. Thus, we can write
$$\begin{align}
|AB||AM|=|AC||AP| &\quad\to\quad \frac{|AB|}{|AC|}=\frac{|AP|}{|AM|} \quad\to\quad \triangle ABC \sim \triangle APM  \tag1\\[6pt]
|YB||YN|=|YC||YQ| &\quad\to\quad \frac{|YB|}{|YC|}=\frac{|YQ|}{|YN|}
\quad\to\quad \triangle YBC \sim \triangle YQN \tag2
\end{align}$$

Matching-up corresponding angles in the similar triangles, we have
$$\begin{align}
\angle AMP &=\angle ACB=\alpha+\beta \tag3\\
\angle APM &=\angle ABC=\alpha+\gamma \tag4 \\[8pt]
\angle YNQ &=\angle YCB=\beta \quad\to\quad \angle BMN = \beta \quad\to\quad \angle AMN=\alpha+\beta \tag5 \\
\angle YQN &=\angle YBC=\gamma \quad\to\quad \angle CQP \;\,= \gamma \quad\to\quad \angle APQ \;\,= \alpha+\gamma \tag6
\end{align}$$
Since $\angle AMP = \angle AMN$, we have that $M$, $N$, $P$ are collinear; likewise for $M$, $Q$, $P$. Let the line through these four points meet $\overline{AD}$ at $Z$; since $Z$ is on the extended common chord $\overline{XX'}$, we have
$$|ZM||ZN| = |ZP||ZQ| \tag7$$
Finally, re-fold the figure along $\overline{AD}$ to restore the three-dimensional tetrahedron. The collinearity of $M$, $N$, $P$, $Q$, $Z$ becomes coplanarity. Moreover, taking the left-hand side of $(7)$ as computing the power of $Z$ with respect to the circumcircle of $\triangle MNP$, the equality with the right-hand side implies that $Q$ must lie on that circle. Done!

Thank you so much for your answer! May i ask if my idea is correct? I think that the case where $ABC$ is obtuse doesn't exist...The only way for it to be obtuse is for angle $BAC$ to be obtuse, but $BAC= \alpha+ \beta$ and if we get in the triangle $BDC$ we get that $\alpha+ \beta <90$ Am I correct? Correct me if I'm wrong?

@IONELABUCIU: There's nothing geometrically wrong with having $\angle BAC$ be obtuse. In fact, you get that case by simply swapping the labels $A$ and $Y$ in the figure (and also $M\leftrightarrow N$ and $P\leftrightarrow Q$). The line through points $M$, $N$, $P$, $Q$ doesn't change. ... One may-or-may-not want to rule this case out because the description claims $Y$ lies on segment $AD$, but that's a semantic technicality. (Likewise, it isn't geometrically necessary to restrict $X$ to the segment, either.)

So to make it clear, the case where BAC is obtuse is still valid, is possible?

@IONELABUCIU: Yes, the case where $\angle BAC$ is obtuse is valid ... provided that you allow $Y$ to lie anywhere on line $AD$ instead of merely within segment $AD$. In formulating the question, it's perfectly reasonable for the author to restrict $Y$ to segment $AD$. For one thing, this keeps all the derived points within the confines of the given tetrahedron (which would seem to make for easier visualization); also, it does the reader a favor by not unnecessarily distracting them with the general case.

And i have one more question and I'm done! I don't understand what you did here: ,,computing the power of $Z$ with respect to the circumcircle of $\triangle MNP$, the equality with the right-hand side implies that $Q$ must lie on that circle.". Can you be more explicit with your explanation? Thank youuu so much1

@IONELABUCIU: Line $ZP$ meets the circumcircle of $\triangle MNP$ at two points, $P$ and, say, $P'$. (This might be the same point if the line is tangent, but that doesn't matter.) We then have $|ZM||ZN|=|ZP||ZP'|$ from the power of $Z$ with respect to that circle. Thus, $$|ZP'|=\dfrac{|ZM||ZN|}{|ZP|}=|ZQ|$$ where the second equality follows from $(7)$. We may conclude that $P'=Q$, so that $Q$ lies on the circle.
